# What is the naming standard for path components?

Tags: path, language-agnostic, cross-platform, filenames, terminology

I keep getting myself in knots when I am manipulating paths and file names because I don’t follow a naming standard for path components.

Consider the following toy problem (Windows example, but hopefully the answer should be platform independent). You have been given the path of a folder:

```
C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\
```

You want to walk the folders underneath and compile all the .src files to .obj files.

At some point you are looking at the following path:

```
C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
```

**How would you name the following path components?**

```
A. foo
B. foo.src
C. src
D. .src
E. C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\ (absolute path of the root)
F. Widget\foo.src (relative path of the file to absolute path of the root)
G. Widget\
H. C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\
I. C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
```

Here is my attempt:

A. Base name? Basename?

B. File name? Filename?
The difference is important when choosing identifier names, and I am never consistent here.

C. Extension?

D. Extension? Wait, that is what I called C.
Should I avoid storing the dot, and just put it in when required?
What if there is no dot on a particular file?

E. ?

F. ?

G. Folder? But isn’t this a Windows-specific term?

H. Path name? Pathname? Path?

I. File name? Wait, that is what I called B.
Path name? Wait, that is what I called H.

Comment: Mike Pope, a technical editor at Microsoft, points out on his [blog that](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=2346) that while the Microsoft style guide sticks consistently to two words:  file name, folder name, volume name, the Apple Style Guide sometimes joins them: filename, pathname, volume name.

Comment: A) should definitely not be called basename because basename is already used in many places to mean the last item in a path (for a file, that would be the filename without dirpath). Some places call the filename without extension the `stem`.

Comment: Also, for files with multiple periods (e.g., foo.src.txt) , is there any standard way of identifying (and naming) the extension/s?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I think your search for a "standard" naming convention will be in vain. Below are my proposals, based on existing, well-known programs.

---

```
A) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                                   ---
```

> Vim calls it *file root* (:help filename-modifiers)

---

```
B) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                                   -------
```

> [file name or base name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename)

---

```
C) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                                       ___ (without dot)
```

> [file/name extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension)

---

```
D) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                                      ____ (with dot)
```

> also *file extension*. Simply store without the dot, if there is no dot on a file, it has no extension

---

```
E) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
   -----------------------------------------
```

> top of the tree
> No convention, git calls it *base directory*

---

```
F) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                            --------------
```

> path from top of the tree to the leaf
> relative path

---

```
G) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
                                            ------
```

> one node of the tree
> no convention, maybe a simple *directory*

---

```
H) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
   ------------------------------------------------
```

> [dir name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname)

---

```
I) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src
   -------------------------------------------------------
```

> [full/absolute path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathname)

Comment: It's getting off-topic, but be careful with the storage of the extension separate to the dot. You need to handle file names of "foo", "foo." and "foo.txt" (and even "foo.txt.bak".)

Comment: hi guys, great example. It would be more easy to read if you put the answer next to the question, instead of using references that forces to scroll up. I make an edit by the way in order to improve that. Grettings

Comment: Victor, since your edit got rejected (wtf guys, this is a very good improvement!) I just did it myself :-)

Comment: Actually, I think the edit makes it much worse. I had to look at the source code to see what each point was referring to. The font used for the `<code>` element is already bold on my system, so I can't see which part of the of the absolute path is bolded. It would be helpful to include the `A)`, `B)`, etc. and to remove the code elements. I'll try suggesting an edit.

Comment: For `1.` (file name only without extension), I decided to go with `File Title` a long ago due to the lack of a clear convention or at least a global consensus.

Comment: For `A` (filename without extension), you could use `stem`. References:  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.file_stem , http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm_1_1sys_1_1path.html#a498ae7b56cdff5b5b3d8f78ed94ac640 , http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition

Comment: @blinry How about a "C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\" vs "C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget" (final slash missing). Is there a difference in naming these two?

Comment: This "dot without extension" thing is strange, and it's a very good point. I think I've never seen a file with a dot at the end. That would mean "no extension" and I'm pretty sure someone will swallow that abandoned dot. It seems to me that it just means the same: "file." or "file" - but yes, in theory these are different. Maybe on Linux they are. MSDOS lists files with no extension if you say "dir *."

Comment: the use of bold to identify parts of the path made those parts hard to discern, at least on my system. I replaced with underlines and fixed font, which should be much easier for people to read on any system, regardless of CSS in use.

Comment: `foo.src` called `file title` in `OPENFILENAMEW` in Windows.

Answer (score 44):

Good question first of all, my +1. This thing bugged me when I had to create a slew of functions in Utility class once. GetFileName? or GetFullName? GetApplicationPath means full path or the directory name? and so on. I come from .NET background, so I think I can add little more to otherwise excellent answer by @blinry.

***Summary:*** (In italics is what I would not use as a programmer)

1. **Path**: Path specifies a unique location in the file system (unless its relative path). Path name is less often used, but I would stick with path - it pretty much explains what it is. Path can point to a file or a folder or even nothing (C:\). Path can be:

   1. **Relative Path**: `My Source\Widget\` is relative path as well as `Widget\foo.src`. Self explanatory.
   2. **Absolute Path** or **Full Path**: Is the fully qualified path that points to the target. I tend to use the latter more often. `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src` is hence full path. See at the end what I call full path that points to a file and that ends as a directory.

   The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29.) and .NET naming for **path** is consistent.
2. **Root Path** or **[Root Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)**: Former is .NET convention while latter is more heard in UNIX circles. Though I like both I tend to use the former more. In windows, unlike UNIX, has many different root paths, one for each partition. Unix systems have one root directory which holds information on other directories and files. Eg. `C:\` is root path.
3. *Folder* or **Folder Name**: `Widget`, `OddThinking` etc in your case. This might be a Windows only convention (in fact its my own odd thinking :)), nevertheless I strongly object to blinry`s answer "Directory". Though for a normal user directory means [the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28file_systems%29) as a folder (like subfolders, subdirectories), I believe from a technical angle "directory" should sound like a qualified address to the target and not the target itself. More below.

   1. **Sub Folders**: With respect to `users` `OddThinking` and `Documents` are sub folders.
   2. **Sub Directories**: With respect to `users` `OddThinking\`, `OddThinking\Documents\` and `OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\` are sub directories. But we do not often need to bother about it, do we?
   3. **Child Folder**: With respect to `users` `OddThinking` is a child folder (as well as sub folder)
   4. **Parent Folder**: For `OddThinking` `users` is its parent folder (Just mentioning different terminologies, no big deal).
4. *Directory* or **Directory Name**: The former to use generally in real life, the latter to be in code. This refers to the fully qualified path (or simply **full path**) till the target's **parent folder**. In your case, `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget` (Yes a directory is never meant to point to a file). I use directory name in my code since directory is a class in .NET and Directory Name is what the library itself calls it. Its quite consistent with [dirname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirname) used in UNIX systems.
5. *File Name* or **[Basename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename)**: Name of the file along with extension. In your case: `foo.src`. I would say that for a non technical use I prefer **file name** (it is what it means for an end user) but for technical purposes I would strictly stick with **basename**. File Name is often used by MS, **but I am surprised how they are not consistent not just in documentation but even in library**. There filename could mean either basename or full path of the file. So I favour basename, that's what I call them in code. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) on wiki too says file name could mean either full path or the basename. Surprisingly even in .NET I can find the usage basename to mean the root name of the file.
6. **Extension** or **Filename Extension** or **File Extension**: I like the last one. All refers to the same thing but what is it is again a matter of debate! [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) says it is `src` while back then I remember reading that many of the languages interprets it as `.src`. Note the dot. So once again my take is, for casual uses it doesn't matter what it is, but as a programmer I always see extension as `.src`.

   Ok I might have tried to fetch some standard usages, but here are two of my conventions I follow. And it is about full paths.

   1. I generally call a full path that point to a file as *file path*. To me file path is clear cut, it tells me what it is. Though with file name I find it as the name of the file, in my code I call it **file name**. It's also consistent with "**directory name**". From the technical side, name refers to the fully qualified name! Frustratingly .NET uses the term file name (so I have my case here) and sometimes file path for this.
   2. I call a full path that ends as a directory a directory. In fact one can call any piece of address that doesn't point to a file a directory. So `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\` is a directory, `C:\users\OddThinking\` is a directory, or even `OddThinking\Documents\My Source\` (better to call it sub directory or even better relative path - all that depends on the context you are dealing with it). Well above I mentioned something different about directory which is directory name. Here is my take on it: I'll get a new path to avoid confusion. What is this `D:\Fruit\Apple\Pip\`? A directory. But if the question is what is the directory or even better directory name of `D:\Fruit\Apple\Pip\`, the answer is `D:\Fruit\Apple\`. Hope its clear.

   I would say it's better not to worry about the final two terms as that is what create the most confusion (for me personally). Just use the term **full path**!

***To answer you:***

1. *with respect to the path you have given*

   A) No idea. Anyways I never needed to get that one alone.

   B) basename

   C) I would just call it file extension for time being, I am least worried since I never needed that alone to be named in my code.

   D) file extension surely.

   E) I do not think this is a general purpose requirement. No idea. In .NET base directory is the same as directory name.

   F) relative path

   G) folder (parent folder to basename `foo.src`)

   H) directory name

   I) full path (or even file name)
2. *in general (sorry for being a bit verbose, just to drive the point home) but assuming `foo.src` is indeed a file*

   A) NA

   B) basename

   C) NA

   D) extension

   E) directory or simply path

   F) relative path

   G) NA

   H) directory or simply path

   I) full path (or even file name)

***Further driving with one example from my side:***

1. Consider the path `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\s.sql`.

   1. `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\s.sql` is the full path (which is a file name)
   2. `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\` is the directory name.
2. Now consider the path `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data`

   1. `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data` is the full path (which happens to be a directory)
   2. `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users` is the directory name.

***Two tips of mine:***

1. I follow this rule of thumb that when it comes to addressing a full address irrespective of its type, I almost always call it "full path". This not only eliminates the use of two terminologies for file path and folder path, it also avoids the potential confusion if you are going to name that of file as file name (which for most users right away translates to basename). But yes if you have to be specific about the type of path, its better to name then file name or directory instead of more generic "path".
2. Whatever it is you would have your own idea in mind, be consistent with it throughout. Have a consensus among team members that this means this and not that.

Now that just from the circle I have some practice. A new brand of terms would be what is used on OS X and android machines. And all these are just about physical paths in filesystem. A whole  new set of terminologies would arise in case of web addresses. I expect someone to fill the void in this same thread :) I would be glad to hear the convention with which you have went ahead..

Comment: For a long time I've been using the word "pathname" to mean the entire absolute path including the full filename. Your answer, others here, and resources elsewhere have changed my mind about that, and now i'll use the word "fullpath" for this, "path" for the location without filename, and "filename" or "name" for the filename itself.

Answer (score 37):

In C++, [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) has devised a nomenclature for the various parts of a path. See the [path decomposition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-decomposition) reference documentation for details, as well as this [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Class%20path-iterators-etc).

Here's a summary based on the tutorial. For:

- Windows path: `c:\foo\bar\baa.txt`
- Unix path: `/foo/bar/baa.txt`

you get:

```
Part            Windows          Posix
--------------  ---------------  ---------------
Root name       c:               <empty>
Root directory  \                /
Root path       c:\              /
Relative path   foo\bar\baa.txt  foo/bar/baa.txt
Parent path     c:\foo\bar       /foo/bar
Filename        baa.txt          baa.txt
Stem            baa              baa
Extension       .txt             .txt
```

#### C++ standard ISO/IEC 14882:2017

Moreover Boost.Filesystem terminology has been adopted by [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) => See [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path#Decomposition)

```
Function name     Meaning
----------------  -------------------------------
root_name()       Root-name of the path
root_directory()  Root directory of the path
root_path()       Root path of the path
relative_path()   Path relative to the root path
parent_path()     Path of the parent path
filename()        Path without base directory (basename)
stem()            Filename without extension
extension()       Component after last dot
```

Comment: What do they call the entire thing then? `path`, `fullpath`?

Comment: @wisbucky The entire thing is called "path" in their nomenclature.

Comment: @wisbucky Fixed the link. Thanks.

Comment: @olibre: Thanks for the C++17 update. But `stem()` is a part of the _filename_, not the _path_.

Comment: Oops, you are right! `std::filesystem::path("/foo/bar.txt").stem()` --> `"bar"` Thanks for pointing out this important detail ;-) Cheers

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: @johnc.j. It's too bad Boost.Filesystem wasn't as well known when the question was first asked. I'd rather adopt the nomenclature of a peer-reviewed library than make something up on my own.

Comment: I should note that the standard itself (fifth edition, 2017-12) doesn't use any of these words. "File name" is used only once and written as two words. On page 26: "The sequences in both forms of header-names are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to headers or to external source **file names** as specified in 19.2."

Comment: @jsv The words appear in the function names, as shown by olibre's edit.

Answer (score 23):

The [Pathlib standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in Python follows this naming convention for path components:

|  | Path | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A. | /x/y/`z.tar`.gz | stem |
| B. | /x/y/`z.tar.gz` | name |
| C. | /x/y/z.tar.`gz` (excluding dot) | N/A |
| D. | /x/y/z.tar`.gz` (including dot) | suffix |
| E. | `/x`/y/z.tar.gz | grand parent path |
| F. | /x/`y/z.tar.gz` | relative path to grand parent path |
| G. | /x/`y`/z.tar.gz | parent name |
| H. | `/x/y`/z.tar.gz | parent path |
| I. | `/x/y/z.tar.gz` | path |

Comment: I want to adopt this but `suffix` instead of `extension`, where did that come? Hust seems so unintuitive.

Comment: Th docs say "PurePath.suffix The file extension of the final component, if any:" I could say I want to call it `shortyendthing`, and call it a synonym too. `Path.extension` does not exist. I get what its for, I don't get why they made up a new name for an existing concept.

Answer (score 8):

### No you're not crazy.

In Windows systems, sometimes the *path of the directory containing the file* is called *path*, which is how it was from the beginning. So, for example,

```
    x:\dir1\dir2\myfile.txt

    Windows:
    --------
        PATH:  x:\dir1\dir2
        FILE:  myfile.txt

    Unix/Linux:
    -----------
        PATH:  /dir1/dir2/myfile.txt
        FILE:  myfile.txt
```

The Unix/Linux approach is a lot more logical, and that's what everyone mentioned above: path including the file name itself. However, if you type "call /?" in the Windows command line, you get this:

```
    %~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
    %~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
    %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
    %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
    %~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
```

So there it is, "path only" and "file name only". At the same time, they refer to the whole string as "fully qualified path name" which is understood as drive letter plus path plus file name. So there's no real truth. It's futile. You've been betrayed.

Anyway,

### To answer your question

This is how I'd name your examples:

```
A: -
B: basename
C: extension
D: -
E: -
F: -
G: -
H: pathname (or dirname or containing path)
I: full name
```

A-D-E-F have no simple nicknames. And since php is probably the most widely known cross-platform language, everyone understands "basename" and "dirname" so I'd stick with that naming. Full name is also obvious; full path would be a bit ambiguous but most of the time it means the very same thing.

Comment: For a long time I've been using the word "pathname" to mean the entire absolute path including the full filename.  Other answers here and resources elsewhere have changed my mind about that, and now i'll use the word "fullpath" for this, "path" for the location without filename, and "filename" or "name" for the filename itself.

Answer (score 5):

After 10 years of hacking around my two pence is:

- Be consistent
- Think recursion

[image]

Example on a Windows machine:

```
File separator: \ 
Line separator: 

Base name: file 
Extension: txt 
Filename: file.txt     

Drive name: C 
Root name: C: (empty on linux) 
Root dir: \ 
Root path: C:\     

Base dir: Source\ 
Base path: C:\Source\ 
Sub dir: project\ 
Sub-sub dir: docs\ 
Relative dir: project\docs\     

Relative path: project\docs\file.txt 
Working dir: C:\Source\project\docs\
Full path: C:\Source\project\docs\file.txt (also 'Absolute path' or 'File path')   

Linux drive dir: C\ 
Linux root path: \C\ 
Linux base path: \C\Source\     

Parent dir: ..\ 
Current dir: .\
```

The linux stuff near the bottom is how bash mounts the drive on Windows systems.

The current directory, or working "directory", is really wherever your program is, but let's use it to keep track of where the current file is we are working on. Type `pwd` into powershell and the result is called a path!

> Directories always end with the file separator and never include the filename. They can easily be appended.
> "Directory name" could refer to any directory in any position (dirName + sep = dir).

> Paths include the root, the filename, or both.

That is, *paths can be formed by adding either the root, filename, or both, to a directory.* (you could differentiate between **paths** and **file paths**, the 'relative path' would then exclude the file name but give the directories from the base to the working directory, though the term becomes redundant as this is properly called the relative directory).

Notice the distinct meanings of keywords:

- name
- directory
- path
- separator

These are then combined with the *parts* of the full path:

- root
- base
- relative
- file

---

Example: root path = root name + root directory

Notice how this works for both Windows and Linux (where the root path is the same as the root directory because the root name is empty).

---

In Java, the output is produced by:

```
package io;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Directory, File, and Path conventions.
 *
 * Directories always end with the file separator and never include the filename. They can easily be appended.
 * - "Directory name" could refer to any directory in any position (dirName + sep = dir).
 *
 * Paths include the root, the filename, or both.
 *
 * <em>On Windows, base directory names can be capitalised.</em>
 */
public class Main {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("io");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String sep = File.separator;
        final String lf = System.lineSeparator();

        logger.info("File separator: " + sep);
        logger.info("Line separator: " + lf);

        String baseName = "file";
        String ext = "txt";
        String fileName = baseName + "." + ext;

        String driveName = "C";

        String rootName = driveName + ":";
        String rootDir = sep;
        String rootPath = rootName + rootDir;

        String baseDir = "Source" + sep;
        String basePath = rootPath + baseDir;

        String subDir = "project" + sep;
        String subSubDir = "docs" + sep;
        String relDir = subDir + subSubDir;

        String relPath = relDir + fileName;
        String workDir = basePath + relDir;
        String fullPath = basePath + relPath;

        logger.info("Base name: " + baseName);
        logger.info("Extension: " + ext);
        logger.info("Filename: " + fileName);
        logger.info(lf);

        logger.info("Drive name: " + driveName);
        logger.info("Root name: " + rootName + " (empty on linux)");
        logger.info("Root dir: " + rootDir);
        logger.info("Root path: " + rootPath);
        logger.info(lf);

        logger.info("Base dir: " + baseDir);
        logger.info("Base path: " + basePath);
        logger.info("Sub dir: " + subDir);
        logger.info("Sub-sub dir: " + subSubDir);
        logger.info("Relative dir: " + relDir);
        logger.info(lf);

        logger.info("Relative path: " + relPath);
        logger.info("Working dir: " + workDir);
        logger.info("Full path: " + fullPath + " (also 'Absolute path' or 'File path')");

        logger.info(lf);
        String linuxDriveDir = driveName + sep;
        String linuxRootPath = rootDir + linuxDriveDir;
        String linuxBasePath = linuxRootPath + baseDir;
        logger.info("Linux drive dir: " + linuxDriveDir);
        logger.info("Linux root path: " + linuxRootPath);
        logger.info("Linux base path: " + linuxBasePath);

        logger.info(lf);
        String parentDir = ".." + sep;
        String currDir = "." + sep;
        logger.info("Parent dir: " + parentDir);
        logger.info("Current dir: " + currDir);
    }
}
```

---

To give an answer to the OP's question:

```
A) foo = base name
B) foo.src = file name
C) src = extension
D) .src = ? (file extension separator + extension)
E) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\ = base path
F) Widget\foo.src = relative (file) path
G) Widget = directory name
H) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\ = working path aka "working directory"
I) C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src = full path, absolute path, file path
```

Answer (score 3):

- `foo` **Filename Without Extension**
- `foo.src` **Filename**
- `src` **Extension**
- `.src` Maybe **Extension With Dot**, but this should not be used. As written this could be a directory name or a filename.
- `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\` **[Absolute] Directory Path**
- `Widget\foo.src` **Relative File Path**
- `Widget` **Directory Name**
- `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\` This is still an **Absolute Directory Path**. If one is root and the other isn't, its up to your variable names to keep track of that, there isn't really a semantic difference there.
- `C:\users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src` **[Absolute] File Path**

"Filename" is a word, so generally we should use "filename" and not "file name" (and Filename not FileName).

The word "Directory" can be replaced with the word "Folder". (Maybe we should use "Directory" at a lower level, but "Folder" is shorter which I prefer.)

It's actually possible to create a semantic framework of all of these types, with semantically valid functions for combining them. For example, a `FolderName` and a `Filename` can be combined to give a `RelativeFilePath`. A `FolderPath` (absolute is implied) and a `RelativeFilePath` can be combined to give a `FilePath` (absolute is implied).

Also, some of these are related; for example a `FilenameWithoutExtension` is a kind of `Filename`, so should be convertible. A `FolderName` is a `RelativeFolderPath`, so should be convertible. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer you could adopt for simple projects:
Have not used the word `path` because its useful to differentiate it with web paths if working with URLs/path too.

```
| name       | example          |
|------------|------------------|
| file       | /foo/bar/baa.txt |
| filename   | baa.txt          |
| stem       | baa              |
| suffix     | .txt             |
| ext        | txt              |
| dir        | /foo/bar/        |
| dirname    | bar              |
| parent     | /foo/bar/        |
| parentname | bar              |
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the leading slash for directories so that they can be appended.

Answer (score 0):

### What is the naming standard for path components?

Whatever it is, you will end up using what suits you best. Here's my approach.

---

> **A:** *"foo"*

- **filename**, **fn**

---

> **B:** *"foo.src"*

- **file**, **f**

---

> **C:** *"src"*

- **extension_name**, **ext_name**, **xn**

---

> **D:** *".src"*

- **extension**, **ext**, **fx**

---

> **E:** *"C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source"*

- **basedirectory**, **basedir**, **bd**

---

> **F:** *"Widget\foo.src"*

- [relative_]**filepath**, [rel_]**filepath**, [rel_]**fp**

---

> **G:** *"Widget"*

- [relative_]**subdirectory**, [rel_]**subdir**, [rel_]**sd**

---

> **H:** *"C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget"*

- [absolute_]**subdirectory**, [abs_]**subdir**, [abs_]**sd**

---

> **I:** *"C:\Users\OddThinking\Documents\My Source\Widget\foo.src"*

- [absolute_]**filepath**, [abs_]**filepath**, [abs_]**fp**

---

**Examples:**

```
f = fn + fx
file = filename + ext
file = filename + extension

f = fn + "." + xn
file = filename + "." + ext_name
file = filename + "." + extension_name

[abs_]fp = bd + [rel_]fp
[abs_]filepath = basedir + [rel_]filepath
[absolute_]filepath = basedirectory + [relative_]filepath

[abs_]fp = bd + [rel_]sd + f
[abs_]filepath = basedir + [rel_]subdir + file
[absolute_]filepath = basedirectory + [relative_]subdirectory + file

[abs_]fp = [abs_]sd + f
[abs_]filepath = [abs_]subdir + file
[absolute_]filepath = [absolute_]subdirectory + file
```