# Filename without extension terminology

Tags: filenames

What is the technical term used for a filename without the extension?

For example in the following file path:

```
C:\Folder\foo.txt
```

What is the terminology used for `foo`?

Comment: I'm a little surprised this question survived. These tend to be migrated to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). In this case, I can't find anything like it on EL&U, but it *was* asked just a few months later on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/337127). (For my money, the best "answers" are in the comments there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just called a "file" if referring to its base name according to wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Answer (score 12):

Lots of citations to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename), but one term on that page that seems to be unambiguous is [`stem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Filename_extensions).  `Stem` seems better than `base name`/`basename` because, in Unix, the `basename` command simply removes the folder path and keeps the extension.

I suspect that most will not think of `stem` as including the folder path, but if you want to be sure, you can say *base name stem* or *stem of the base name*.  It shouldn't be necessary, though.  There is a lot of confirmatory information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235173/what-is-the-naming-standard-for-path-components).

Answer (score 1):

Extensionless is what I typically use and hear used.

Answer (score 1):

A `'file'`, or `'blank file'` maybe.

Also the part before the dot is called a `'basename'`, `'base name'`, `'filename'`, or a `'file name'`.